# How to solve this homogeneous ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

so I came across an ODE in my textbook, where I'm just given the differential equation and the solution to it, but I don't see how got to it. The problem is the following:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=0 $$
With the general solution given as:
$$ y(x)=-\frac{C_1}{r}+C_2 $$

Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are integration constants. How can that differential equation be solved if the RHS is 0?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=0$$
$$\int\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)dx=C_1$$
$$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=C_1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{C_1}{x^2}$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int\frac{C_1}{x^2}dx$$
$$y=-\frac{C_1}{x}+C_2$$

Answer (score 2):

If you take some time to think about the notation, it would be written as
\begin{align}
\left( x^2 y' \right)'=0 &\implies x^2 y' = c_1\\
&\implies y' = \dfrac{c_1}{x^2}\\
&\implies y(x) = -\dfrac{c_1}{x}+c_2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is $0$ iff the function is constant. Knowing that, you just have to put:
$$x^2 \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = K$$
where K is a constant.

At this point you have to solve (for $x \neq 0$):
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{K}{x^2}$$
which is easy to solve since it has separable variables:
$$y= K \int \frac{dx}{x^2} = K \left( -\frac{1}{x} + C \right) = -\frac{K}{x} + KC$$
and so $c_1=K$ and $c_2=KC$.